# ASP.NET Identity: handling more than one type of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Identity.

I have two type of users

1. Student
2. Teacher

I need get some unique information from each type of user based on theirs type.

student: username, password, email, address, telephone, age,...

teacher: username, password, email, address, category, price, description,...

I thinking about role-based authentication. is it the best solution? 
Is it a good idea to store both user types' information in one table (ASPNetUser table)? or there is another way to store them in sperate tables?

Comment: My suggestion is use ASPNetUser table only for authentication purpose(that includes..  username, password, email). Other than that, create Student and Teacher table with the fields you want. From there, you can use role-based authentication.

Comment: best way is to use AspNetUser, and also you have to create table of user types

Answer (score 0):

Claim based authorization is suitable for your scenario. 
Check this link below for claim based authorization.

https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/introduction-to-claims-based-authentication-and-authorization-in-net/

With claim based authorization you can store different information for different type of user.

For student you can store information as claim.
For teacher you can store different information as claim.

However you will need to store this information in separate table. You can create separate User metadata table where in you can store this information and separate table to store login credential.